# Python 3.5 and openpyxl installation process

Tags: python, openpyxl

I just installed Python3.5.4 and version 2.5 of Openpyxl 2.5. I'm using Windows 10 (64bit).

What I have done so far is that I copied the openpyxl folder into Python's lib folder. In the Command Prompt when I run:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

I am getting an error about "jdcal" and when I run:

```
pip install jdcal
```

I am getting the same error. As you can see on the image "error". With this, I have summarized my queries below,

1. Is Openpyxl2.5 is compatible with Python3.5?
2. Is this something to do with pip? Do I need to install pip?
3. Do I need to install **jdcal**?

the error says:

> could not create c:\program files\python35\lib\site packages\jdcal.py

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run as an admin. You can right click command prompt and run as admin or you might be able to use,

```
sudo pip install openpyxl
```

to get it to work.